# Combine array items by name with a separator?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code which runs a MySQL query and returns the results as an array:

```
function mysql_resultTo2DAssocArray ( $result) {
    $i=0;
    $ret = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $ret[$i][$key] = $value;
            }
        $i++;
        }
    return ($ret);
    }
$compare = mysql_resultTo2DAssocArray(mysql_query("SELECT Temp.School, Temp.Status, Snow.Token FROM Temp
 JOIN Snow ON Temp.School = Snow.School"));
```

The results of this look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [School] => School Name 1
            [Status] => Delayed Two Hours
            [Token] => Token1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [School] => School Name 1
            [Status] => Delayed Two Hours
            [Token] => Token2
        )

)
```

Is it possible to combine the `Token` items by a comma within those arrays if the `School` item is the same for each?

One thing is that it's possible for there to be more arrays within the global array, with different `School` names, that shouldn't be grouped but left alone. Basically, is it possible to ONLY group when `School` is the same. It's also possible for there to be more than two tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Temp.School, Temp.Status, GROUP_CONCAT(Snow.Token) Tokens
FROM Temp JOIN Snow USING (School)
GROUP BY Temp.School
```

This isn't completely valid, because the `Status` column is not aggregated or part of the `GROUP BY`; however MySQL normally allows it (there's an option to disallow it, I don't remember the name offhand). If there are rows with different Status values, it will pick one of them arbitrarily; you didn't say what should happen with different Statuses.